# ErrorMessage in CustomAttributeValidation Guid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, custom-attributes, modelstate

I need help to customize a ErrorMessage sent from Guid Custom Attribute Validation Class.

default error message: "**The value '(MyValue)' is not valid for (MyProperty).**".

It works for other DataTypes like: String, int, int?.

Note #1: This problem only occurs when the guid object is null or invalid.

Note #2: The invalid causes the guid to be null, the oficial documentation says:

Note #3: None these methods in IsValidGuid class works.

Note #4: If Guid is valid, my custom ErrorMessage in dataannotation works.

```
     Summary:
         Initializes a new instance of the System.Guid structure by using the specified
         array of bytes.

     Parameters:
       b:
         A 16-element byte array containing values with which to initialize the GUID.

     Exceptions:
       T:System.ArgumentNullException:
         b is null.

       T:System.ArgumentException:
         b is not 16 bytes long.
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório")]
    [IsValidGuid(ErrorMessage ="Guid inválida")]
    public System.Guid? MyGuid { get; set; }
}
```

**IsValidGuid**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class IsValidGuid : ValidationAttribute
    {
        //public override bool IsValid(object value)
        //{
        //    if (value == null)
        //    {
        //        return false;
        //    }

        //    Guid guidOutput;

        //    if (Guid.TryParse(value.ToString(), out guidOutput))
        //    {
        //        if (guidOutput.ToString().Equals("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"))
        //        {
        //            return false;
        //        }

        //        return true;
        //    }

        //    return false;
        //}

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {


            if (value == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage ?? "Test");
            }

            Guid guidOutput;

            if (Guid.TryParse(value.ToString(), out guidOutput))
            {
                if (guidOutput.ToString().Equals("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"))
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(base.ErrorMessage);
                }

                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }

            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage ?? DefaultErrorMessage);
        }
    }
```